# Connecting company observations when using a Lasso Regression in R Studio

Tags: r

I am using R to predict company net income using compustat data. I am utilizing Lasso regression.

I got the code for the Lasso regression working, however I am getting very low R^2 values.

I think this is because in the model I need to use a matrix so the gvkey and fyear are input as a double type (the regression sees these as an input not a unique identifier) so it cannot match/use that firms prior years net income as input to estimate the next year since it is not matching each firms prior years to their future years.

Sorry, I hope that makes sense - let me know if there is any other information needed.

Comment: Welcome on stack Ian. When making posts it is always good to include your code otherwise we can't really help you and understand what's going on.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example